# Access PHP $_SESSION using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, dashboard

I try to feed and retrieve data in a `$_SESSION` variable in PHP using AJAX.

Here is my scenario :

[image]

A laptop is browsing to *admin.php* webpage that's saved on the srv-web server. This server (raspberry PI) is itself plugged on a big screen used as a dashboard and the webpage *index.php* (localhost) is displayed over the screen.

The Hello World message is stored in `$_SESSION['msg']` variable.
The form in *admin.php* is feeding that variable using the user input as a value

**admin.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['msg'])) { 
$_SESSION['msg'] = $_POST['msg']; 
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
}
?>
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="msg" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So far, the dashboard was using a `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=index.php">` to refresh the message sent by the admin laptop.

This solution can't be use anymore as some data can't be refreshed on the webpage. I thought about using ajax aside PHP to get this setup to work. Here is what I have so far :

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var session;
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
    $.get('getsession.php', function (data) {
        session = data;
    });
</script>
<?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**getsession.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
print json_encode($_SESSION['msg']);
?>
```

As you can guess, I am not a javascript developer and I can't get this code to work. Nor any I have found on the Internet (I can't write this kind of code of my own yet and this is a bit pressing).

Would anyone be kind and help me to retrieve the data from `$_SESSION['msg']`  and to display it without refreshing *index.php* ?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Looks like your code is not completed yet. You need to assign the content of `session` to some dom element. (e.g. `document.getElementById('someid').textContent = session;`) and you need to repeatedly make the ajax request. (e.g. with `setInterval`)

Comment: @RolandStarke I have enclosed the whole javascript inside a `setInterval(function(){  ... }, 3000);` and added `document.getElementById('someid').textContent = session;` in the function aside a `<h1 id='someid'></h1>` inside the body, still it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you specify "not working" You can see errors opening the developer tools with F12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an input like this :

```
<input type="text" id="yourVal" value=""></input>';
```

and then refresh the value in an interval in js like this :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('getsession.php', function (data) {
       document.getElementById("yourVal").value=data;
    });
}, 200);
```

I don't know how your JSON looks like so i can't show how to get the data value properly

**Edit** : Apparently, @DanFromGermany pointed that timeout is a better practice. Here's what you could do to make sure you won't get stuck

```
var interval = 1000; // 1 sec
var keepGoing = true;
function execAjax() {
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'session.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("yourVal").value=data;
        },
        error:{
           keepGoing=false;
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            // Schedule the next
            if(keepGoing==true){
                setTimeout(execAjax, interval);
            }
        }
    });
}
setTimeout(execAjax, interval);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Using your solution aside google I've been able to get it to work, finally! :D

Comment: Best practice is not using `setInterval` with ajax. Use a recursive `setTimeout` instead. If you have a timeout or latency in the ajax call when using `setInterval`, your browser gets backlashed and you dos yourself.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thank you sir ! thanks for sharing your thoughts too !